# toolstripmenu события

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Есть toolstrip меню, одинаковое в каждом из 30 окон. На меню есть события по клику, приходится их копировать из окна в окно, как можно оптимизировать и объявить все события с этим меню в одном месте?

Comment: Создайте UserControl в основе которого будет toolstrip и используйте данный элемент в своих окнах.

Comment: @sp7 хз почему, но выдает ошибку и удаляет из списка ресурсов user contol'ы

Comment: Сложно сказать почему не видя Вашего кода.